# Stuck on html 2 xml conversion

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Im relatively new to xslt and stuck at the moment with an html 2 xml conversion script. I did manage to get the basics done but some issues are a bit too deep for me and was hoping if someone could point me in the right direction. The situation is as follows:

I have an html file which i already converted a little bit which looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.beloningenbelasting.nl/dtd/bb.xslt"?>
<!-- Copyright 2017 Fiscaal up to Date BV, Eindhoven NL -->
<!DOCTYPE BeloningEnBelasting SYSTEM "http://www.beloningenbelasting.nl/dtd/bb.dtd">
<BeloningEnBelasting>
    <body>
       <div  id="_idContainer000">
            <p>remove</p>
        </div>
       <div  id="_idContainer001">
            <p>remove</p>
        </div>
       <div  id="_idContainer002">
            <p>remove</p>
        </div>
        <div id="_idContainer003">
            <p>info of id 4 could be here</p>
        </div>
        <div id="_idContainer004">
            <p class="Body-Text-Extra" lang="en-US">Hoofdrubriek</p>
            <p class="DUkopartikel">art. nr. en titel</p>
            <p class="platte-tekst">platte tekst met erin: 
                <span class="cursief">tekst cursief</span>
                <span class="vet">tekst vet</span></p>
            <p class="Bodytextvet">bold tekst</p>
            <p class="DUinspring">List item</p>
            <p class="DUbron">bron</p>
            <p class="Body-Text-Extra" lang="en-US">Hoofdrubriek</p>
            <p class="DUkopartikel">art. nr. en titel</p>
            <p class="platte-tekst">platte tekst met erin: 
                <span class="cursief">tekst cursief</span>
                <span class="vet">tekst vet</span></p>
            <p class="Bodytextvet">bold tekst</p>
            <p class="DUinspring">List item</p>
            <p class="DUbron">bron</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="_idContainer005">
                <p>kan weg</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</BeloningEnBelasting>
```

The results should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.beloningenbelasting.nl/dtd/bb.xslt"?>
<!-- Copyright 2017 Fiscaal up to Date BV, Eindhoven NL -->
<!DOCTYPE BeloningEnBelasting SYSTEM "http://www.beloningenbelasting.nl/dtd/bb.dtd">
<BeloningEnBelasting>
    <artikel id="manual input and copy paste">
        <uitgave>manual input and copy paste</uitgave>
        <datum>manual input and copy paste</datum>
        <rubriek>
            <hoofdrubriek></hoofdrubriek>
        </rubriek>
        <titel></titel>
        <tekst>
            <p> with <i>cursive</i> and <b>bold</b> text</p>
            <ol>
                <li>orderned list</li>
            </ol>
            <ul>
                <li>unorderned list</li>
            </ul>
        </tekst>
    <noten>
        <noot>...</noot>
    </noten>
    <bronnen>
        <bron>...</bron>
    </bronnen>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="manual input and copy paste">
        <uitgave>manual input and copy paste</uitgave>
        <datum>manual input and copy paste</datum>
        <rubriek>
            <hoofdrubriek></hoofdrubriek>
        </rubriek>
        <titel></titel>
        <tekst>
            <p> with <i>cursive</i> and <b>bold</b> text</p>
            <ol>
                <li>orderned list</li>
            </ol>
            <ul>
                <li>unorderned list</li>
            </ul>
        </tekst>
        <noten>
            <noot>...</noot>
        </noten>
        <bronnen>
            <bron>...</bron>
        </bronnen>
    </artikel>
</BeloningEnBelasting>
```

As you can see almost all the data in `<div id="_idContainer004">` or in `<div id="_idContainer003">` should be divided in multiple `<artikel>`s.

I wrote the following xsl to do the first steps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p[@class= 'DUbron']">
        <bronnen>
            <bron>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </bron>
        </bronnen>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="p[@class= 'platte-tekst']">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </p>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="p[@class= 'Bodytextvet']">
        <p>
            <b>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </b>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[@class= 'bodycursief']">
        <p>
            <i>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </i>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[@class= 'DUinspring']">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="span[@class= 'vet']">
        <b>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </b>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="span[@class= 'cursief']">
        <i>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
        </i>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[@id= '_idContainer000']|div[@id= '_idContainer001']|div[@id= '_idContainer002']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This xsl only cleans up the document but im stuck to create the `<artikel>` format and to apply the right `<rubriek><hoofdrubriek>main title</hoofdrubriek></rubriek>` because this title is given only once every few articles and applies to the proceeding articles until there is a new one.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Kind regards,

AJ

PS original html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Bel&amp;Bel_2017_15</title>
    </head>
    <body id="Bel-Bel_2017_15" lang="nl-NL">
        <div id="_idContainer000">
            <p class="colofon" lang="en-US">unused data</p>
            <p class="colofon" lang="en-US">unused data</p>
            <p class="colofon" lang="en-US">unused data</p>
            <p class="colofon" lang="en-US">V</p>
        </div>
        <div id="_idContainer001">
            <p class="datum" lang="en-US">unused data</p>
            <p class="datum" lang="en-US">unused data</p>
        </div>
        <div id="_idContainer002" class="Basistekstkader">
            <p class="Inhoud" lang="en-GB"><a href="">unused data</a></p>
            <p class="Inhoud" lang="en-GB"><a href="">unused data</a></p>
            <p class="Inhoud" lang="en-GB"><a href="">unused data</a></p>
        </div>
        <div id="_idContainer004">
            <p class="Body-Text-Extra" lang="en-US">Hoofdrubriek</p>
            <p class="DUkopartikel">art. nr. en titel</p>
            <p class="platte-tekst">platte tekst met erin: 
                <span class="cursief">tekst cursief</span>
                <span class="vet">tekst vet</span></p>
            <p class="Bodytextvet">bold tekst</p>
            <p class="DUinspring">List item</p>
            <p class="DUbron">bron</p>
            <p class="Body-Text-Extra" lang="en-US">Hoofdrubriek</p>
            <p class="DUkopartikel">art. nr. en titel</p>
            <p class="platte-tekst">platte tekst met erin: 
                <span class="cursief">tekst cursief</span>
                <span class="vet">tekst vet</span></p>
            <p class="Bodytextvet">bold tekst</p>
            <p class="DUinspring">List item</p>
            <p class="DUbron">bron</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="_idContainer005">
                <img src="Bel&amp;Bel_2017_15-web-resources/image/Advertenties_APP_FINAL_ZW.png"
                    alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see that my post got something mixed up but all the info i need to use to create the article are in div id ...003 or in div id ...004. How can I make it so that the script automatically detects the right div and deletes the other?

Comment: Your input isn't an HTML file, it's just an XML file with HTML-like elements such as `div` (XSLT can't parse HTML, even though it can output HTML-like markup)

Comment: I know, as i mentioned i already did the first part of the conversion and stuck with that output, as the main HTML files has too much unused data. This is the result of my first step. I can include the original html file if that helps?

Comment: I can't see the title you want to output, but you generally would use `<xsl:value-of select="...XPath expression ..."/>` to fetch content from higher-up content nodes from within your templates.

Comment: It's rather difficult to work out the relationship between the input and the desired output, since most of the input appears to be in Dutch(?) while the output is in English...

Comment: I think you may be looking for `xsl:for-each-group` here, used with `group-starting-with`. Probably something like `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="p[class='Body-Text-Extra']">`